# max string lenght for cakephp hash function

Tags: cakephp, hash

Is there a some maximum length restriction for the string for the cake [hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security%3a%3ahash) function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only available memory (i.e. you have to be able to load the string as a whole). The hash *output* always has the same length, though.

If you want to hash a large data blob that won't fit into memory you must process it in chunks. PHP has some functions for it (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php). The basic steps are:

1. Create a hashing structure (`hash_init`)
2. Read chunks, update the hash structure (`hash_update`)
3. After the last chunk, finalize the hash and get the output (`hash_final`)

For your convenience, PHP has `hash_update_file` and `hash_update_stream` wrappers.

Comment: Thanks @JvO for the answer, actually I am talking about a strings with length kind of 1000 - smth like that, will it be ok about the memory and should in that case I follow the steps you wrote . Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Strings of that size should not be a problem at all.